# Removing and recreating a tkinter window with a restart button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code for a game where you have to click the mosquito in time. If you don't, you lose and can restart by clicking the Restart Button. But when I get to that point, the window just closes and re-opens and I can't click anything. How can I fix it? (Note: I am new to Python)

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from time import *


def replace():
    global score
    global initialized
    global start
    end = time()
    timeneeded = end - start
    label.config(text="")
    if timeneeded > (2-score/20) and initialized > 0:
        lose()
    else:
        z1=randint(0,950)
        z2=randint(0,660)
        button.place(x=z1,y=z2)
        start = time()
        initialized = 1
        score=score+1

def lose():
    text="Diesmal hast Du zu lange gebraucht!\n"
    text+="Du hast insgesamt "+str(score)+" Mücken erwischt!"
    label.config(text=text)
    label.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=CENTER,fill=BOTH)
    restartButton=Button(window, text = "Nochmal?", command = restart())
    restartButton.place(x=700, y=350)

def restart():
    global start
    global score
    global initialized
    global mosquito
    global z1
    global z2
    global button
    global label
    global window

    try:
        if('normal' == window.state()):
            window.destroy()
    finally:
        score = 0
        initialized = 0
        start=time()
        window =Tk()
        # mosquito=PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Downloads/mosq45.png")
        mosquito=PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Julian/Downloads/mosq45.png")
        z1=350
        z2=350
        initialized = 0
        start=time()
        score = 0
        window.title("Fang die Mücke!")
        window.geometry("1020x740")
        button=Button(window,image=mosquito,command=replace)
        button.place(x=z1,y=z2)
        label=Label(window,font=("Arial",32),text="Fang so viele Mücken wie möglich!")
        label.place(x=10,y=200)
        window.mainloop()



window =Tk()
# mosquito=PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Downloads/mosq45.png")
mosquito=PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Julian/Downloads/mosq45.png")
z1=350
z2=350
initialized = 0
start=time()
score = 0
window.title("Fang die Mücke!")
window.geometry("1020x740")
button=Button(window,image=mosquito,command=replace)
button.place(x=z1,y=z2)
label=Label(window,font=("Arial",32),text="Fang so viele Mücken wie möglich!")
label.place(x=10,y=200)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Creating a button with `command = restart()` means that you call `restart()` *at the moment the button was created*, and do nothing at all when the button is clicked (because `restart()` returned None).  You want `command = restart`, specifying a function to call later.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you, it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

Define the refresh/restart function in the main. And destroy the root and reinitiate the process again. Bind this function to any button in your main GUI. Hope this helps.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

def vp_start_gui():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    """ INSERT YOUR WHOLE CODE HERE"""
    """ CREATE A BUTTON AND ITS command = refresh() which is defined at the bottom"""
    root.mainloop()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def refresh():
        root.destroy()
        vp_start_gui()

    vp_start_gui()
```